# Having trouble sending items in lists through Email(python)

Tags: python, email, smtp

I want to send some data(in lists) through Email using python but I am facing an issue. Here is my code:

```py
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
tokens = ['stfen1','stfen2','stfen3','stfen4','stfen5']
ids = ['idfstfen1','idfstfen1','idfstfen1','idfstfen1','idfstfen1',]
num = 1
EMAIL_ADDRESS = ('example@gmail.com')
EMAIL_PASSWORD = ('password')
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = f'EMP Data'
msg['From'] = f'Name <{EMAIL_ADDRESS}>'
msg['To'] = f'Name <{EMAIL_ADDRESS}>'
for token,id in zip(tokens,ids):
                msg.set_content(f'Data\n{num}: Account ID->{id}--Account Token->{token}\n')
                num += 1
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

The Output I'm expecting in my email is:

```py
Data
1: Account ID-> idfstfen1--Account Token-> stfen1

Data
2: Account ID-> idfstfen1--Account Token-> stfen2

Data
3: Account ID-> idfstfen1--Account Token-> stfen3

Data
4: Account ID-> idfstfen1--Account Token-> stfen4

Data
5: Account ID-> idfstfen1--Account Token-> stfen5
```

The output I'm getting:

```py
Data
5: Account ID-> idfstfen1--Account Token-> stfen5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `msg` variable first, and concatenate `token` and `id`s in the for loop

```
msg = ''
for token,id in zip(tokens,ids):
            msg += f'Data\n{num}: Account ID->{id}--Account Token->{token}\n'
            num += 1
msg.set_content(msg)
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
           smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
           smtp.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: It sent 5 different emails,

Comment: @Zen35X Does the edited version help it now?